# How to place a horizontal rule under table header?

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to place a horizontal rule `<hr />` underneath a table header `<th>` with close to no success. Is this possible without hacks?

Here is the `HTML` I'm using and what I've tried to far

```
<div id="epd" class="editProfileDiv">    
    <form>
        <table align="center">
            <th> Profile Information </th>
            <tr> 
                 <hr />                  
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name: </td>        
                <td><input id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?>" placeholder=" Jon Doe" type="text" class=""></td>
            </tr>
```

That code appears like this in the browser

```
----<hr/> is here----
 Profile Information
 Name:  <text input>
```

Then I tried this

```
<th> Profile Information </th>
<hr />                  
<tr><td> something here </td></tr>
```

Which has the exact same outcome, the `<hr/>` is on top of the table header

and this...

```
<tr> 
  <td> <hr /> </td> // If I only use one it only spans half the width of the table
  <td> <hr /> </td>                  
</tr>
```

which places the `<hr/>` in the correct place but there is obviously a gap between them which is *not* what I want.

Now I know I can just **not** use a table header, and use a regular paragraph or any text for that matter and style it however I want. At this point it's just the principal because this is bugging me. So again, the question: Is this possible?

Comment: Note that this is misuse of the [`hr` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tr> 
  <td colspan="2"> <hr /> </td>      
</tr>
```

Comment: =) thanks buddy. The one thing I probably didn't try. Answer will be accepted asap

Comment: ps, love your website. That heavy drop shadow when the nav links are pressed is sexy. Gives a very 3D feel to the "button press" action